# Different Request.Browser values on deployed app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-11

I'm working on an MVC4 application, and one of the tasks I've had to do was to detect the browser/device from which a request is sent. Naturally, I used MVC's Request.Browser object like this:

```
var browser = Request.Browser.Browser;
var deviceManufacturer = Request.Browser.MobileDeviceManufacturer.ToLower() != "unknown" ? Request.Browser.MobileDeviceManufacturer : "desktop";
var deviceModel = Request.Browser.MobileDeviceModel.ToLower() != "unknown" ? Request.Browser.MobileDeviceModel : "desktop";
```

However, it seems that when making the request to localhost from IE, the correct browser is shown in the 'Browser' property. However, when making a request to the deployed app, instead of saying 'InternetExplorer', the Browser property is set to 'Mozilla'.

Another issue related to it is that the only devices that seem to be detected are IPhones and IPads, although our QA told us that they tested is with kindle fire, android devices as well. I'm not sure what the User-Agent is in those cases but I will update the question as soon as I find out.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: IE 11 identifies itself as Mozilla/Gecko now

Comment: Here is a solution that I think fits: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999989/internet-explorer-11-detection-on-server-side

Comment: thanks for the link, somehow I haven't found it before

Comment: No worries. It made me scratch my head for a while too