# HttpCapabilitiesBase.Type Property - reliability

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, httpwebrequest

Accroding to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.type(v=vs.100).aspx), `HttpCapabilitiesBase.Type` property:

> Gets the name and major (integer) version number of the browser.

For example, if the client is using Chrome version 36.0.1985.143, then
`Request.Browser.Type == "Chrome36"`

Now, how reliable is this info?

- Which browsers does it support?
- Are browsers displayed accurately?

Note: Users tampering with their request is no worry here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "not very", but depending on what you need, that might not be a concern for you.

HttpCapabilitiesBase works by matching the browser's User-Agent string against the browser information that the .NET Framework ships with. This information is stored in a collection of .browser files. Depending on which platform and .NET Framework version you are using, you can find the files at:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Browsers
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Browsers
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\Browsers
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\Browsers

Microsoft updates these files infrequently via service packs, [hotfixes](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx) or with [new releases](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/01/ie11-browser-detection-aspnet), but these  updates aren't particularly frequent. As such, an update is only needed when an existing browser changes it's user-agent string, or a new browser with a new user-agent is launched. While this happens quite infrequently in the desktop browser world, it's a much bigger issue in the mobile browser world.

The .browser support for mobile browsers has frequently been [found lagging](http://forums.asp.net/t/1899139.aspx?System+Web+Configuration+HttpCapabilitiesBase+IsMobileDevice+seems+to+be+inconsistent+for+Android+devices). If proper detection of mobile browsers and their capabilities is important to you, then you will need to use a third-party device database.

The [ASP.net Mobile](http://www.asp.net/mobile) website links to 51Degree's [Foundation](http://51degrees.codeplex.com/) project which maintains a frequently updated [device capability database](http://51degrees.com/Products/Device-Detection). Note that there are free, as well as commercial versions available, with [differing capabilities](http://51degrees.com/Prices).

A similar option is the [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) device repository, which also has free and commercial licenses available.

Alternatively, if you just want to maintain support for a very small subset of known browsers that aren't supported out of the box in .net, you can implement and use your own BrowserCapabilitiesProvider  as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20847920/1473915) by user [Doug Domeny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113701/doug-domeny). I would not recommend this if you have a large set of browsers to support though. That way lies madness.:)