# Microsoft Edge regex for user agent

Tags: php, regex, user-agent, microsoft-edge

Is there a fool-proof regex (I'm using PHP) to match the Microsoft Edge user agent string?

Comment: [Which one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30591706/what-is-the-user-agent-string-name-for-microsoft-edge)?

Comment: `preg_match("/Edge\/12\./", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $output_array);`

Comment: I'm curious -- what would the use case be?

Comment: Nothing special, just playing around.

Comment: /(edge)[ \/]([\w.]+)/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would HIGHLY recommend

1. not using us-sniffing. There is almost *no* reason to do so.
2. if you *absolutely really have to*, using a library like [ua-parser](https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser/tree/master/php) rather than rolling your own.

Comment: 1. Working around fun browser bugs is a good reason. 2. A library vs. one line of code, guess it depends on how accurate the match has to be.

Comment: 1. feature detecting the bug is 100% more reliable than ua sniffing. 2. the one line of code will almost always be worse, long term

Comment: The issue I had was with setting a header for redirects. MSIE display unicode characters in the redirected URL nicely if its not encoded, Edge needs it to be encoded.

Not sure how to future detect in backend: `header("LOCATION: /".(preg_match("/Edge\/1(2|3|4)\./", getenv('HTTP_USER_AGENT'))) ? rawurlencode("sök") : "sök");`

Comment: that is a 100% valid case for ua sniffing. but that detect literally breaks yesterday because of the release of Edge 15. using a ua parsing library would prevent that. That being said, if you can create a sample case that shows this behavior (either static file or httpbin or something), I work on Edge, I can help get it fixed.

Comment: The issue in question is fixed (EdgeHTML issue tracker #8477507), the regex only targets versions of Edge that's affected by the bug... ;-) Again, it depends on how accurate the detection needs to be and the purpose of the sniff. A good rule of thumb, user agent sniffing is **always** unreliable so never trust the information and always have an fallback in place.

Answer (score 9):

As well most browsers you can simply just say the browser name in the comparison string as shown below.

```
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
preg_match('/Edge/i', $user_agent)
```

This worked for me. Hope it does for you too.